# Qt Quick (QML) color declaration

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I have following statement inside `ListView` declaratation:

```
highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
```

Everything is ok, but I was just wondering, which file in is word `lightsteelblue` declared, so I can review other predefined colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-color.html) says it is normally specified as an **SVG color name**, and provides [this reference page](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords). I understand QML supports the different keyword names listed in there.

EDIT: as pointed out by @dbrianj (thanks), you can find them in the [qtbase/src/gui/painting/qcolor_p.cpp](http://download.froglogic.com/public/qt5-squishcoco-report/QtBase/source_355.html#line132) file.

Comment: @KeillRandor ok, but the must be declared somewhere in Qt installation, which file?

Comment: you might be looking for qtbase/src/gui/painting/qcolor_p.cpp